# Twisted url action routing

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web, twisted.internet

If I have for example this simple TCP server:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.web.server import Site

from resources import SomeResource


logging.info("Starting server...")
root = Resource()
root.putChild("test", SomeResource())
reactor.listenTCP(8080, Site(root))
reactor.run()
```

With SomeResource which has the render_GET and render_POST methods for example.
Then I know I can just send a POST/GET to hostname:8080/test

But now I want to make it more complicated, I would like to do something like hostname:8080/test/status

Could that be defined inside SomeResource() as a method? or do I have to define a new resource for every different url?

Comment: http://twisted.readthedocs.io/en/twisted-16.2.0/web/howto/web-in-60/dynamic-dispatch.html should help you out.  If your code gets really complicated, I would recommend Klein https://github.com/twisted/klein which is much simpler to write.

Answer (score 2):

If you want everything that goes to /test/.... to get to the render (render_GET/render_POST) method of SomeResource, just define it as a [leaf](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/using-twistedweb.html#resource-objects):

```
class SomeResource(Resource):
    isLeaf = True
```

If you want to look at the part after "test/", request.postpath will include that.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response! would that solution be similar to use getChild method then redirct it?

Comment: No, don't do that. You'll lose information from the request that way (request.postpath).