# Generate a site dynamically using Twisted

Tags: python, twisted

I want to generate all the pages of a site using `twisted`. It has to be similar with [generating a page dynamically](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/dynamic-content.html).

I came up with this :

```
class Home(Resource):
    isLeaf = False

    def __init__(self, pathname):
        Resource.__init__(self)
        self.pathname = pathname

    def getChild(self, name, request):
        if name == '':
            return self
        return Resource.getChild(self, name, request)

    def render_GET(self, request):
        path = "/var/www/html/books.toscrape.com/catalogue/"
        fname = path + self.pathname
        if ".html" in self.pathname:
            f = open(fname)
            s=f.read()
            return s
        else:
            fname = fname + "/index.html"  
            f = open(fname)
            s=f.read()
            return s  

class ElseSite(Resource):
    def getChild(self,name,request):
        return Home(name)

resource = ElseSite()
factory = Site(resource)
```

I'm able to generate pages with the url `localhost:8080/foo`, but how can I add more slashes to it, i.e. something like `localhost:8080/foo/bar`?

Comment: Did you intend to ask a question?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone Sorry, added my doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Children themselves can have children:

```
from twisted.web.resource import Resource

class Foo(Resource):
    def getChild(self, name, request):
        return Bar(name)

class Bar(Resource):
    def getChild(self, name, request):
        return Data(name)

site = Site(Foo())    
...
```

You may also want to take a look at [Klein](https://klein.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which provides for a different style of defining your hierarchy.  From the Klein docs:

```
from klein import Klein
app = Klein()

@app.route('/')
def pg_root(request):
    return 'I am the root page!'

@app.route('/about')
def pg_about(request):
    return 'I am a Klein application!'

app.run("localhost", 8080)
```

The native Twisted Web style is nice for very dynamic resource hierarchies.  The Klein style is nice for relatively fixed hierarchies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This answer helped me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37689813/217088.

Answer (score -1):

This answer helped me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/37689813/217088.

I defined a single resource with `isLeaf = True`, and then used `request.postpath` to get the query after `http://localhost:8080/`.

My code looks like this now :

```
class Home(Resource):
    isLeaf = True

    def __init__(self):
        Resource.__init__(self)

    def render_GET(self, request):
        path = "/var/www/html/books.toscrape.com/"
        filepath = '/'.join(request.postpath)
        fname = path + filepath
        f = open(fname)
        s=f.read()
        return s

resource = Home()
factory = Site(resource)
```

Comment: This is a very problematic implementation of `render_GET`.  Please consider a request for a path like `../../../../etc/passwd`.  This is _not_ a good way to implement a Resource.

Comment: I understand the fault here. Thanks!